# Automating Setting Sharepoint File Properties

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have multiple files which I replace regularly in SharePoint. These files have properties like release number and file name that are not identical and have minor changes each time. Is there a way to automate setting the properties in such a way that the properties can be set and edited in a single text file and some tool can be used to read the text file set the properties as specified for each file?

Comment: Power automate flow or PowerShell can help with such activities. Reading the excel/csv file, match common field in file & document library and updated the properties of matched file in library.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding by reading your question, would suggest to use 'Lookup' columns in doc lib.

You can create a list to store the properties which you want to refer in the doc lib.

[image]

Then create one 'Lookup' column in doc lib to refer the properties from list.

[image]

By this approach, all the changes which you make into the list will get automatically reflected into the doc lib properties as well. (*"Is there a way to automate setting the properties in such a way that the properties can be set and edited in a single text file and some tool can be used to read the text file set the properties as specified for each file?"*)